# Consulta e alteração simultânea

Tags: sql, select

Considerando uma tabela parecida com essa:

```
Tabela : [Frutas] ╔════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Fruta  ║   Cor   ║ Mordida ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  Maçã  ║  Verde  ║   Não   ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ Banana ║ Amarela ║   Não   ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  Pera  ║  Verde  ║   Não   ║
╠════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║  Uva   ║   Roxo  ║   Não   ║
╚════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

Sendo que, por exemplo, 5 pessoas podem realizar a consulta ****ao mesmo tempo**** e "Morder" uma fruta. Como eu posso para garantir que nenhuma pessoa tente morder a mesma fruta ?

(Obs: Se a consulta é realizada ao mesmo tempo, todas as pessoas vêem a fruta como Não mordida naquele instante, então um simples `SELECT * Frutas WHERE Mordida = "Não"` NÃO TEM EFEITO)

Comment: Exatamente, o que significa que não se faz isso com SELECT. De qualquer forma, não existe "ao mesmo tempo" em DB, tudo é enfileirado (exceto em sistemas distribuídos, mas isso é outra história)

Comment: Sim, o que eu quero saber é como se faz...

Comment: Tem maneiras e maneiras. Uma delas é UPDATE fruta SET mordido = 1 WHERE fruta = banana AND mordido = 0 - A condição do update é exatamente não estar mordida. Não são feitas 2 operações, é uma só. Aí você vê se o registro foi ou não alterado com sucesso.

Comment: Outra delas é você controlar as mordidas separadamente, numa "lista de mordidas": INSERT INTO mordidas SET fruta = 1 sendo que fruta é um índice UNIQUE (tipo "highlander", só pode haver um)

Comment: É um classico problema de controle de transação. Você precisa determinar quais são as premissas. Se cinco pessoas podem pegar a mesma fruta epodem [ou não] mordê-las você não terá impedir (nesse caso a última mordida é a que ficaria 'registrada'). Se ao pegar uma fruta a pessoa tiver que declarar se irá ou não mordê-la é outra história. Ou ainda se ela pode pegar a fruta indeferentemente e ao tentar morder registrar apenas se a fruta não já estiver mordida...

Comment: `SELECT` é usado para selecionar registros, ou seja, não altera. Para alterar dados você usa o comando `UPDATE`. Ainda assim, o SELECT pode ou não mostrar registros que estão "sendo alterados", isso do nível de isolamento onde o comando `SELECT` está sendo executado

Comment: Sobre a questão do "não morder já mordido", e a pessoa não ter que ficar clicando e receber uma mensagem "fruta já mordida" e atualiza a sua tabela, vai depender do seu front. Se o seu front é atualizado somente com solicitação ou se é automático (ex.: de 1 em 1 segundo). Claro que o que irá mandar por trás, é seu UPDATE.

Answer (score 6):

Você já partiu do princípio certo: que `SELECT` não presta para a finalidade desejada.

É um engano muito comum, inclusive que vemos em códigos aqui no site: contar com não haver mudança nenhuma entre um `SELECT` e a operação seguinte. Mas essas mudanças acontecem.

Maneiras de resolver há muitas, vou falar algumas das mais óbvias:

```
UPDATE fruta SET mordido = 1 WHERE fruta = banana AND mordido = 0
```

A condição do update é exatamente não estar mordida. Não são feitas 2 operações, é uma só. Aí você vê se o registro foi ou não alterado com sucesso.

Outra delas é criar um ***index* `UNIQUE`**, e executar esta *query*:

```
INSERT INTO mordidas SET fruta = 1
```

O `UNIQUE` faz com que haja uma falha se houver tentativa de inserir valor(es) repetidos.

Desta forma, você está armazenando uma lista de mordidas, sem o risco de ter duas frutas diferentes. Sendo UNIQUE o índex, você testa se teve sucesso ou não a inserção.

Ainda: supondo que você tenha varias fruteiras, pode criar um `UNIQUE( fruteira, fruta )`, ou seja, pode morder frutas iguais de fruteiras diferentes, ou frutas diferentes da mesma fruteira, mas não pode morder a mesma fruta da mesma fruteira.

Note que mencionei duas maneiras muito comuns e fáceis de implementar, mas cada situação merece seu tratamento específicos.

O que é comum na maioria delas, é que depois da tentativa, você vai ter que mostrar o resultado para o usuário, mas aí é questão de interface.

O comentário do colega @DiegoRafaelSouza pode se aplicar dependendo do cenário:

> *É um classico problema de controle de transação. Você precisa determinar quais são as premissas. Se cinco pessoas podem pegar a mesma fruta e podem [ou não] mordê-las você não terá como impedir (nesse caso a última mordida é a que ficaria 'registrada'). Se ao pegar uma fruta a pessoa tiver que declarar se irá ou não mordê-la é outra história. Ou ainda se ela pode pegar a fruta indeferentemente e ao tentar morder registrar apenas se a fruta não já estiver mordida.*

Dependendo do caso, você vai precisar de mecanismos adicionais. Mas quase todos podem se aproveitar dos dois exemplos de *query* acima.

Exemplo para 5 mordidas:

```
UPDATE tabela SET mordidas = mordidas + 1 WHERE fruta = 1 AND mordidas < 5
```

Answer (score 2):

O que você precisa é trabalhar com transações no banco de dados. A implementação pode varia dependendo do SGBD que você estiver utilizando, mas seguem todos os mesmos princípios do ACID:

**Atomicidade:**

Todas as ações que compõem a unidade de trabalho da transação devem ser concluídas com sucesso, para que seja efetivada. Se durante a transação qualquer ação que constitui unidade de trabalho falhar, a transação inteira deve ser desfeita (rollback). Quando todas as ações são efetuadas com sucesso, a transação pode ser efetivada e persistida em banco (commit).

**Consistência:**

Todas as regras e restrições definidas no banco de dados devem ser obedecidas. Relacionamentos por chaves estrangeiras, checagem de valores para campos restritos ou únicos devem ser obedecidos para que uma transação possa ser completada com sucesso.

**Isolamento:**

Cada transação funciona completamente à parte de outras estações. Todas as operações são parte de uma transação única. O principio é que nenhuma outra transação, operando no mesmo sistema, possa interferir no funcionamento da transação corrente(é um mecanismo de controle). Outras transações não podem visualizar os resultados parciais das operações de uma transação em andamento (ainda em respeito à propriedade da atomicidade).

**Durabilidade:**

Significa que os resultados de uma transação são permanentes e podem ser desfeitos somente por uma transação subsequente.Por exemplo: todos os dados e status relativos a uma transação devem ser armazenados num repositório permanente, não sendo passíveis de falha por uma falha de hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Ultilizar BEGIN TRANSACTION para truncar a tabela e COMMIT para liberá-la

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SELECT * Frutas WHERE Mordida = "Não";
    COMMIT;
```