# Melhor forma de garantir isolamento de consulta

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, windows-service

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Uma tabela no SQL Server que contém registros de processos que podem ser executados em vários serviços (*Windows Services em C#*) de vários servidores. Algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE Processo
(
    Id          INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Status      VARCHAR(100)
)

GO

INSERT INTO Processo VALUES 
  ('Aguardando processamento'), ('Aguardando processamento'), ('Aguardando processamento')

SELECT  *
FROM    Processo 

/*
| Id  | Status                   |
| 1   | Aguardando processamento | 
| 2   | Aguardando processamento | 
| 3   | Aguardando processamento | 
*/
```

Os serviços consultam esta tabela simultaneamente buscando um processo com status "Aguardando processamento". Assim que um destes serviços encontra o processo, o status é atualizado para "Processando" em um método mais ou menos assim:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("string de conexão"))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Top 1 Id FROM Processo WHERE STATUS = 'Aguardando processamento'";
        int processo = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE Processo SET STATUS = 'Processando' WHERE Id = @Id";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", processo));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }                
}
```

O problema acontece quando no meio tempo entre a consulta e a alteração do status para "Processando" em um serviço "A", um serviço "B" encontra o mesmo registro e também começa a processar.

> Eu preciso garantir que quando um serviço encontre um processo, nenhum outro possa encontrar ou alterar este mesmo registro.

**Qual é a melhor maneira de garantir isso?**

EDIT: O objetivo da minha pergunta é resolver o problema considerando aplicações .NET em múltiplos servidores, o sugerido como "possível duplicada" ([291665](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291665/consulta-e-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-simult%C3%A2nea)) não abrange a tecnologia utilizada e as respostas não se aplicam ao meu caso.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Consulta e alteração simultânea](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291665/consulta-e-altera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-simult%c3%a2nea)

Comment: @ramaral Na verdade minha pergunta é mais específica e acho que a mencionada não tem respostas muito práticas para este caso. Editei para deixar claro isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode executar ambos os comandos dentro de uma transação usando `SqlTransaction`:

```
using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Top 1 Id FROM Processo WHERE STATUS = 'Aguardando processamento'";
        int processo = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE Processo SET STATUS = 'Processando' WHERE Id = @Id";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", processo));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    trans.Commit(); 
}
```

Referência do MSDN: [SqlTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: uma vez que o código rode em vários computadores, seria bom colocar o nível de isolamento da transação como `Serializable`, o banco irá se encarregar de tratar as concorrencias

Comment: @RovannLinhalis sim é uma boa ideia, uma vez que o padrão é *ReadCommited*.  Para quem quiser se aprofundar mais, aqui o link da documentação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.isolationlevel(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @RicardoPontual Obrigado. Neste caso é melhor abrir a transação e isolar tanto o select como o update (como foi feito), ou apenas no select já garantiria o isolamento ?

Comment: Você seta o *IsolationLevel* para toda a transação, então vai valer para o select e o update

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoPontual, usei sua resposta com o `conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)` para garantir o isolamento e funcionou.